# Why does Chrome revert changes in Sources panel?

Tags: sass, google-chrome-devtools

I have a local sass file mapped to its network equivalent in Dev Tools Sources. I can edit in sources, my local file is updated, the css updates (via grunt), and the changes are reflected on the live site. So far, so good. The problem is as soon as Chrome updates with the new CSS it also reverts the local sass in Sources to the network sass. Why is this happening?

I've included a video so you can see what's happening. You can see right at the very end of the video the local sass that I've completely deleted switches back to the network sass which is still there: https://youtu.be/xdZjtBGDAWA